# Submitting a Login Form using Python 3.1

Tags: python, networking

I am trying to login to this website: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/ucp.php?mode=login by using a Python 3.1.3 script. At the time, I have this:

```
import webbrowser
import urllib.request
import cgi
import cgitb
import urllib.parse
import hashlib
import http.cookiejar

p = urllib.parse.urlencode({'username':'MYUSERNAME','password':"MYPASSWORD"})

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
o = urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj) )
urllib.request.install_opener( o )

f = o.open( 'http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/ucp.php?mode=login',  p )
data = f.read()
f.close()
htm = open("file1.html", "w")
htm.write(str(data))
htm.close

f = o.open( 'http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/PAGEFORWHICHLOGINISREQUIRED' )
data = f.read()
f.close()
htm = open("file2.html", "w")
htm.write(str(data))
htm.close

print('fin')
```

However, when I run this code, file1.html contains the login form itself (no messages) and file2.html contains the "you are not logged in" page.

Could somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong? Sorry for my incompetence, I am rather new to Python. Thank you in advance!

P.S. Might it concern MD5 hashing the password? I've been working with the hashlib library, and haven't been having much luck. If this is the case, could somebody please explain how I would go about hashing my password?

Answer (score 1):

When I submit this form, the login button is submitted as `&login=Login`. Perhaps this form requires that you submit that also?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be a lot better off using `Mechanize`. It's particularly useful for form submissions.